# Prove $ \operatorname{Var}(X_{(n)})\leq E(X_{(n)}-X_{(n-1)})^2 $

Tags: probability

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}$
Let the random variables $ X_1, X_2, ... , X_n $ be independent with $ EX_k^2 < \infty $ for any $k$ .Let $ X_{(1)} \leq X_{(2)} \leq ... \leq X_{(n)}$ be the corresponding order statistics. Prove that, no matter what the distribution of the $ X_i $ is
$$ \Var(X_{(n)})\leq E(X_{(n)}-X_{(n-1)})^2 $$
Proof:
$$
\Var(X_{(n)})\leq E(X_{(n)}-X_{(n-1)})^2
\\
\\
\Var(X_{(n)}) = E(X_{(n)}-EX_{(n)}- X_{(n-1)}+X_{(n-1)})^2 \geq 0
\\
\\
\Var(X_{(n)})=E(X_{(n)}-X_{(n-1)})^2-E(X_{(n-1)}-EX_{(n)})^2
\\
\\
\Var(X_{(n)})+E(X_{(n-1)}-EX_{(n)})^2=E(X_{(n)}-X_{(n-1)})^2
\\
\\
\Var(X_{(n)})\leq Var(X_{(n)})+E(X_{(n-1)}-EX_{(n)})^2=E(X_{(n)}-X_{(n-1)})^2
\\
\\
\Var(X_{(n)})\leq E(X_{(n)}-X_{(n-1)})^2
$$

Did I solve it correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure the step after $E(X_{(n)} - E X_{(n)} - X_{(n-1)} + X_{(n-1)})^2$ is correct.

Comment: @angryavian Here is the full proof: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17_iTtZfKnl5MuUxeAA1Yx3K2nEyPFOPa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @FaxriddinTojiboyev It's not true in general that $X_{(n-1)}$ and $X_{(n)}$ are independent I believe, even with the independence assumptions on $X_i$.

Comment: @pax Could you give any counter-examples or facts, please? Thanks in advance

Comment: I mean, $\mathbb{P}(X_{(n-1)}>X_{(n)})=0$, but if they were independant, we would have that $0=\mathbb{P}(X_{(n-1)}>a,X_{(n)}<a)=\mathbb{P}(X_{(n-1)}>a)\mathbb{P}(X_{(n)}<a)$. Thus taking, for example, $n=2$ and $X_i$ iid Gaussian, we get a counterexample, as both of these are positive.

Comment: @pax I got it. Thanks!

Comment: (1) Are the $X_i$ in your question identically distributed? (2) The setup in your comment link is not the same as your post. Your post considers order statistics, but your comment considers a running maximum of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$.

Comment: @angryavian 1) No, they are not identically distributed. 2) I just wanted define $ X_{(i)} $ as $ Y_i $

Comment: @FakhriddinTojiboev You should edit your question then. Note that $Y_2 = \max\{X_1, X_2\}$ is not the same as the second order statistic of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. (Unless your definition of $Y_i$ was a mistake on your part.)